# Downloading vcpkg-glibc... and jump out when trying install vcpkg

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, vcpkg

this is the first time I asked in Stack Overflow. Sorry if I don't ask it properly.

I am using Ubuntu 20.4 to install Vcpkg then I can install some other C++ libs.

However, when follow the tutorial from their [website](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) .

```
Step 1: Clone the vcpkg repo

git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git

Make sure you are in the directory you want the tool installed to before doing this.

Step 2: Run the bootstrap script to build vcpkg

./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
```

I met this issue. it start downloading then jump out. Installation seems failed.

```
My Ubuntu:~$ ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
Downloading vcpkg-glibc...
My Ubuntu:~$ vcpkg
vcpkg: command not found
```

There isn't any error or warning information. I also didn't find any similar issues on Internet. So I really don't know how to fix that....

Comment: Use `cd vcpkg` and then `./vcpkg` ;)

Comment: The reason for the second error is that `vcpkg` is not in your current path - do not add it either as the command uses relative paths. You must specify it as mentioned by Osyotr.

Comment: @Osyotr Thanks for your help. Now I received "bash: ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh: Not a directory"   why it says it's not a directory? I am still confused, sorry.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your help. But I think I didn't install it properly. even if I cd vcpkg firstly. I would receive "vcpkg: command not found"

Comment: I would delete and setup vcpkg again.

Comment: @JohnHanley You mean redo git clone? I wasn't install at all I think. But I will try tomorrow as you said!